# behavior of calling function of unmanaged dll is different between console app, asp.net app with iis express, and asp .net app on real iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, unmanaged

[Resolved] this behavior was actually caused by the 64 bit version of the program (the dll is not compatible with 64 bit). When the program is running in 32 bit everything is fine (in all platform).

I actually integrate a piece of code on my app in order to read an chip card connected on the usb port.
The code was furnished by french social security (the dll and the .net wrapper of the unmanaged code) so i don't have documentation, neither support on this. the dll was built on the top of PKCS #11

I made the development on a console app and it works well.

Nom i integrate this on my asp.net webapp .net framework 4.0 (yes the chip card will be connected on the usb of the server) and the problems begin.

- with iisexpress, same behavior than the console app, it works well
- on real iis, i don't have exception but the code act like there is no chip card. No exception, just it don't detect the card.
- still on real iis, i changed the type of application pool to Local Service. With this, the chip card is now detected, but i have a bug somewhere in the code (really obscure code, i don't write it. In some line of code it expect receive an object which is null and it finished on null reference exception).

I don't know what to do now. so guys if you have some ideas which can help me to understand this behavior  and make it work on real iis, I take it. Now i don't have any other solutions.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 You need a complicated architecture with multiple processes in different sessions to properly solve the issue, or simply run on IIS Express if acceptable.

Comment: According to your description, I cannot determine your problem. Can you provide more information about your problem? For example, is there any error messages on real iis?

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved] this behavior was actually caused by the 64 bit version of the program (the dll is not compatible with 64 bit). When the program is running in 32 bit everything is fine (in all platform)